# Pasar respuesta ajax a php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

estoy haciendo una consulta ajax de un sitio web externo. Recibo bien los datos de sitio pero en json, me gustaria enviar la respuesta a php. Este es el codigo ajax

```
var datos = {"Nombre:" : "Alejandro"};
var url = "http://quasar.e-htl.com.br/booking/hotels-availabilities";
    $.ajax({                        
       type: "POST",                 
       url: url,                    
       data: datos,
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data)            
       {
        console.log(data);
         $('#resp').html(data);           
       }
     });
```

Yo recibo bien los datos de la url y me lo muestra en el console.log, pero me gustaria mandarlos a php

Comment: puedes decir que tipo de error te da ?

Comment: Haz otra petición ajax al fichero php que quieras tener los datos

Comment: Deberás hacer otra petición ajax como ya han comentado, aunque me gustaría hacer un apunte. ¿Por qué no aprovechas la petición que ya estás haciendo para ejecutar ahí todo el código de servidor de una sola llamada?

Answer (score -1):

Te dejo un código que puede ayudarte:

function enviar(valor1,valor2){

```
    var parametros = { "variable1" : valor1,"variable2" : valor2 };

    $.ajax({
          data:  parametros,
          url:   'destino.php',
          type:  'post',        
          beforeSend: function() { $('#resultado'+valor1+'').html('<p>Procesando...</p>');},
          error: function() { $('#resultado'+valor1+'').html('<p>Error</p>'); },                 
          success:  function (response) { $('#resultado'+valor1+'').html(response); }
    }); }
```